# Booting centos from a VHD in Hyper V

Tags: windows, hyper-v

I am working on moving a bootable VHD running CentOS to a new VM. This is on Windows Server 2019 with Hyper-V version 10.0.17763.1. This VHD is working. Here are the steps I have taken:

1. In Hyper-V click on New-->Virtual Machine
2. Step through the configuration steps with the following options differing from defaults; 4 CPU, Generation one, Add VHD later.
3. I complete the setup and then click settings on the newly created machine choosing IDE 0 and selecting the vhd in question as its target.
4. I then start the machine and when I connect, all I see is a blinking cursor.

I am not sure where I am going wrong here, but if anyone can provide some things to check it would be appreciated.

Comment: What do you know about the image? Was it set up to boot in UEFI mode?

Comment: Good question, unfortunately my predecessor set it up so I am not sure.

Comment: Where is it being "moved" from? Hardware and operating system platform.

Comment: Mount the volume in a different VM and figure out how it is configured?

Comment: @GregAskew it is being moved within the same machine, Windows Server 2019. I was a victim of the bug where VM's disappear. The Microsoft solution is to take the VHD and spin up a new instance.

Comment: What a curious series of events. Try running from a live boot ISO and attach the disk to have a look see?

Comment: Yes it is very frustrating. Lost visibility to a mail server and a file server.

Comment: Have you set the first boot device as the vhd in the settings?

Comment: @Turdie yes I did, moved it to the top of the list of devices to boot from.

Comment: @GregAskew I attempted to mount the drive on the VM and running fdisk -l did not show the device. I then attempted to mount the disk in windows and it states that the disk has unrecognized partitions. Any thoughts there?